# Joomla Less Mixin wont work

Tags: css, joomla, less, mixins, compiled

im new to less and im trying a little bit around, ive found a mixin code snippet which should work but it doesnt. Just if i take the variables on top of the reset.less document it works.
So i guess my Joomla Less compiler couldn't compile it right. But as im new to less i dont now if the code is appropriate.
I was trying following code:

```
    .inner-shadow (@x: 0, @y: 1px, @blur: 2px, @spread: 0, @alpha: 0.25) {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
    box-shadow:         inset @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
    }
```

After i written it that way it worked:

```
    @x: 0; @y: 1px; @blur: 2px; @spread: 0; @alpha: 0.25;
    .inner-shadow{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
    box-shadow:         inset @x @y @blur @spread rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
    }
```

Comment: The first method is a parameterized mixin (whereas the second isn't). Parameterized mixins must be called from inside another selector block for it to be output in CSS. Is your code doing that? I cannot see anything wrong with the mixin code. If called in the right way, it should produce output.

Comment: @Harry 
its a pity but it isnt working in my case.
It doesn't produce any output

Comment: Can I see the full code and how it is called? Could you post it in CodePen or CSSDeck or JSBin (all of them support Less)?

Comment: Yes of course just a minute sorry for the lated answer
How i call it in global.less 
http://pastebin.com/TVDpAUgh

How the less file looks(reset.less):

http://pastebin.com/su7NFfQp

Comment: The code seems to be of the second version (which as you had indicated worked fine). Please post the code that you are trying when using the first method.